# NCA R12 with LoadRunner 12.02 - nca_get_top_window returns NULL

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, oracleforms

Connection successfully established by nca_connect_server() but i am trying to capture current open window by using nca_get_top_window() but it returns NULL. Due to this all subsequent requests fail

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you obtained your script, whether it recorded or manually written.
If script is written manually there is guarantee that it could be replayed, since it may happen that sequence of API (or/and its parameters) is not valid. If script is recorded – there might be missed correlation or something like this, common way to spot the issue – is to compare recording and replaying behavior (by comparing log files related to these two stages, make sure you are using completely extended kind of log files) to find out what and why goes wrong on replay,  and how it digress from recording activity.